How to create a JavaScript function to remove specific arguments from an array?
I wrote the following code, which has failed my test as I did not get the expected output [1, 2, 4].
const removeFromArray = function(array,...removeThis) {
   for (let i=0;i<removeThis.length;i++){
      array.splice(array.indexOf(removeThis),1);
   }
   return array;

};

removeFromArray([1, 2, 3, 4], 3)

To debug, I tried printing the individual variables to the console. The results are as follows:

removeThis.length returns 1 (this works)
removeThis returns [3]
array.indexOf(removeThis) returns -1 (this does not work)

From the docs:

The indexOf() method of Array instances returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.

I'm not sure why my indexOf() is not working and how I can fix this piece of code to get the expected output of [1,2,4].
My current output is [1,2,3].
EDIT: This is the full challenge statement, which involves passing all the tests
const removeFromArray = require('./removeFromArray')

describe('removeFromArray', () => {
  test('removes a single value', () => {
    expect(removeFromArray([1, 2, 3, 4], 3)).toEqual([1, 2, 4]);
  });
  test('removes multiple values', () => {
    expect(removeFromArray([1, 2, 3, 4], 3, 2)).toEqual([1, 4]);
  });
  test('removes multiple of the same value', () => {
    expect(removeFromArray([1, 2, 2, 3], 2)).toEqual([1, 3]);
  });
  test('ignores non present values', () => {
    expect(removeFromArray([1, 2, 3, 4], 7, "tacos")).toEqual([1, 2, 3, 4]);
  });
  test('ignores non present values, but still works', () => {
    expect(removeFromArray([1, 2, 3, 4], 7, 2)).toEqual([1, 3, 4]);
  });
  test('can remove all values', () => {
    expect(removeFromArray([1, 2, 3, 4], 1, 2, 3, 4)).toEqual([]);
  });
  test('works with strings', () => {
    expect(removeFromArray(["hey", 2, 3, "ho"], "hey", 3)).toEqual([2, "ho"]);
  });
  test('only removes same type', () => {
    expect(removeFromArray([1, 2, 3], "1", 3)).toEqual([1, 2]);
  });
});


Why would you expect the length of the array to be [1, 2, 4]?!

sorry... that part was my debug code to find removeThis.length. I have modified the question to include the original code

removeThis is an array. indexOf does not expect an array as argument.

Please provide the text of the code challenge you have been given.

There are these issues:

removeThis is an array, as you have defined the parameter list with rest parameter syntax. indexOf does not expect an array as argument. Maybe you intended to do indexOf(removeThis[i])?

If that problem is fixed, then only the first occurrence of the value will be removed. So this would not be good enough if the array can have multiple instances of the value to be removed.

It would remove the wrong value when the value to be removed does not occur at all in the array. In that case indexOf returns -1, and passing that as argument to splice will remove the last element of the array.


There is a handy array method, filter, that was invented for returning an array with values that meet some condition. This is a good use case for using it:


const removeFromArray = function(array,...removeThis) {
   return array.filter(value => !removeThis.includes(value));
};

const result = removeFromArray([1, 2, 3, 4], 3);
console.log(result);



For large inputs (many parameters) this will be not the most efficient. If large inputs are possible, then create a Set of the values to be removed:


const removeFromArray = function(array,...removeThis) {
   const forbidden = new Set(removeThis);
   return array.filter(value => !forbidden.has(value));
};

const result = removeFromArray([1, 2, 3, 4], 3);
console.log(result);



